# Does energy pulse stack per orb?

Tags: warframe

I'm a fan of the Zenurik school, which has this handy ability:

> **Energy Pulse:** Energy pickups grant 25% / 30% / 35% / 40% / 45% / 50% additional energy over 10 / 9 / 8 / 7 / 6 / 5 seconds.

This results in a slow trickle of energy after picking up an energy orb.  However, I'm starting to wonder if it's more energy-efficient to pick them all up at once, or to wait and slowly pick them up one at a time.

What happens when I pick up a second orb while still gaining energy from a first orb?  Do I gain energy faster?  Longer?  Does the buff just reset (resulting in lost potential energy)?

Comment: I'd imagine it doesn't stack, because the Zenurik energy regeneration from void dash doesn't stack either; But then again nothing is forcing DE to be consistent.